# How can I query out all the data by given a list param using Capsule?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I use [Capsule](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Capsule.html) for query database,

this is my database table:

[image]

the `ip_content` field type is text.

now I want to use capsule query out the data by passing a ip list,

such as pass `[12.1.1.1, 13.2.2.5, 14.2.2.8]` param, I want to get the servers all upper out.

in my way I only can think out use double for-loop to make it come true, so is there any other way to achieve it, more efficiencily.

Comment: can you provide the code that you have tried?

Comment: what is the data type for `ip_content`? Because I see multiple ips in this column is text/array/json? And yes as @ab.in said provide some code.

Answer (score 1):

Yo can do like this

```
SELECT server_name FROM table 
WHERE ( ip LIKE '%12.1.1.1%' OR ip LIKE '%13.2.2.5%' OR ip LIKE '%14.2.2.8%' )
```

Or you can use **match against query**

1. Change table engine to MyISAM because InnoDB dont support FULL TEXT Search
2. Create Full Text Index on column ip_content Like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `IP_INDEX` (`ip_content`);
```

3. set ft_min_word_len = 1 in ini file of MYSQL
4. Restart Mysql
5. `REPAIR TABLE`table`QUICK`

and then run query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` 
WHERE MATCH(ip_content)  
AGAINST ('"13.2.2.5" "12.1.1.1" "14.2.2.8"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

use **inverted commas** and **space** to separate ips/words

Comment: There maybe inaccuracy, ` LIKE '%13.2.2.5%' ` will matching `13.2.2.51` or `13.2.2.52` and so on. its not `13.2.2.5`.